# Sql: Selecting from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables. Player and Stats. Player has the fields: Name, Age, DOB and SSN. Stats has the fields: Tackles, Goals, Assists, and SSN. SSN is a foreign key. How can I write a query to find the stats of players with DOB >= '1994'. DOB is not a foreign key, I was wondering how that could work.

Comment: I think you can do something like SELECT players.* from players, stats WHERE players.SSN = products.ssn AND DOB >= 1994, if you want one statement without using Join. Join is, of course, the more standard option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Player INNER JOIN Stats ON Player.SSN = Stats.SSN WHERE Player.DOB >= '1994-01-01'
```

If you just want specific fields then specify these instead of SELECT *

Comment: Need to make that `>=` rather than `>`

Answer (score 3):

this is a simple Join commmand.

```
SELECT * FROM Stats 
INNER JOIN Player
On Player.SSN = Stats.SSN
WHERE DOB > 1994
```

there is an issue from here however as you imply that DOB is a string, not a datetime or Integer with those quotes. you cant compare Strings as numbers like you are trying to do. if DOB is just year e.g. 1994, then `DOB >= 1994` would work, if its a `date` or `datetime`, you need to use `Datetime` equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

```
select player.name, stats.tackles, stats.goals, stats.assists
from player inner join stats on player.ssn = status.ssn
where year(player.dob) >= 1994
```